# Jenkins nightly deployment

Tags: maven, jenkins, nightly-build

I have a jenkins server that have a maven job.
today we are not deploying artifacts to our repository(Artifactory) since it takes a lot of time(30 minutes).
than we are invoking  an integration-tests  on other jobs (different machines too, slaves) that test it on different databases (oracle, sqlserver) and different os (linux, windows).

What i want to do is to make a nightly deployment of all our maven modules.

My questions are:

1.What is the proper way to do it, should we put our logic on some maven profile or should i use jenkins to invoke this profile i.e 
`mvn -Pdeployprofile deploy`

If we use jenkins should it be on same job or not?. 
My thought is that on day jenkins would run : `mvn install` 
on night: `mvn deploy`

How can i achieve that?

Thanks a lot David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a separate job, triggered on a schedule, using a separate maven profile.  That makes it easier to trigger the job manually, for testing, or if you need to do a push of a hot-fix build, or if you get a faster build cluster,